# NoReverseMatch on django generated views

Tags: django

I'm trying to create the views for all the authentication process in Django, but I have an issue with the reverse url tag in the views.

I have : 
urls.py

```
url('^v1/back/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
```

login.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" action=".">
  {{ form.as_p }}

  <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Log in' %}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>

<p>{% trans "Forgot password" %}? <a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.auth_password_reset' %}">{% trans "Reset it" %}</a>!</p>
<p>{% trans "Not member" %}? <a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.registration_register' %}">{% trans "Register" %}</a>!</p>
{% endblock %}
```

And when I access localhost:8000/v1/back/login/ i have:

> NoReverseMatch at /v1/back/login/
>
> Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.auth_password_reset' with
>   arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s)
>   tried: []

The thing is, as, you can see, i try putting the complete path, it still does not work.
When I try to access another view like password change, it redirects me to :

> http://192.168.56.103:8000/accounts/login/?next=/v1/back/password_change/

Which obviously does not work, and when i access password reset :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" action=".">
  {{ form.as_p }}

  <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Submit' %}" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

It has the django admin look and feel instead on my base.html.

I'm guessing there are lots of problem here, I'm trying to solve them one by one, but i don't know what i've done wrong on the url part.

Don't know if this is relevant, but a part of my application is served by Django Rest Framework, and i'm trying to put in place oAuth2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct name for password reset is just [`password_reset`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/urls.py#L14), to reverse it use:

```
{% url 'password_reset' %}
```

To fix the login redirect, you have to adjust the [LOGIN_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#login-url) in your settings.py

I suggest you remove the part regarding the template and post it as a separate question.